# How do you find the intersection(s) of two circles with equal radii?

Tags: geometry, circles

I have two circles with the following equations:
\begin{equation*}
(x-a_1)^2+(y-b_1)^2=r^2 \\
(x-a_2)^2+(y-b_2)^2=r^2
\end{equation*}
The two radii are equal. How do you find the intersections of any two circles with equal radii?

Comment: There is a nice article in wolfram: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html

Comment: This isn't a duplicate of the other question of which it's marked a duplicate (at least, the way all answers to the other question seem to be interpreting it-- the other question isn't completely clear).  This is a simpler question, because the two radii are equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that you have $(x-a_1)^2+(y-b_1)^2=r^2=(x-a_2)^2+(y-b_2)^2$

That you transform in

$(x-a_1)^2-(x-a_2)^2=(y-b_2)^2-(y-b_1)^2$

$a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$ thus you have

$(a_2-a_1)(2x-a_1-a_2)=(b_1-b_2)(2y-b_2-b_1)$

or

EDIT: forgot the factor 2, thanks for the comments!

$y=\dfrac{(a_2-a_1)(2x-a_1-a_2)}{2(b_1-b_2)}+\dfrac{b_2+b_1}{2}$

Don't forget that you have also to verify the first equations, so you have to plug this into one of them...

Comment: Shouldn't there be a factor of $2$ in the denominator?

Comment: Should be $y=\dfrac{(a_2-a_1)(2x-a_1-a_2)}{2(b_1-b_2)}+{(b_2+b_1) \over 2}$

Comment: Just an aside, I suggest leave the answer as this form $(a_2-a_1)(2x-a_1-a_2)=(b_1-b_2)(2y-b_2-b_1)$, since $b_1$ and $b_2$ can be $0$ as the same time. i.e. Two circles that have center $(0,0)$ and $(2,0)$ with radii $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Simply equate them: the points of intersection belong to both circles, and thus verify
$$(x_i-a_1)^2+(y_i-b_1)^2=(x_i-a_2)^2+(y_i-b_2)^2$$
where $(x_i,y_i)$ are the coordinates of the intersection points.

Answer (score 0):

Simplify the equations, subtract one from,the other, express y trough x or x through y, and then put it in one of the original equations.

Now you can find the intersection points.